# How to merge multiple UIImageViews into one UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, camera

I have 2 UIImageViews laying on top of each other ( picture + overlay frame ) and I want to save them to the camera roll as 1 picture.

How should I combine those 2 UIImageViews so that I can call the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function, using a 'result' UIImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have my Mac nearby at the moment, but I have done this before.
The process is that you'll render the `UIImageView`s into a bitmap context, then create a `CGImage` from that context that you can use to create a new `UIImage` from.
Read up on [`CGBitmapContext`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html), including [`CGBitmapContextCreateImage`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreateImage)

Answer (score 15):

```
+ (UIImage * ) mergeImage: (UIImage *) imageA
                                 withImage:  (UIImage *) imageB
                                 strength: (float) strength {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imageA.size.width, imageA.size.height), YES, 0.0); 

[imageA drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0)];

[imageB drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0) 
          blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal // you can play with this
              alpha: strength]; // 0 - 1

UIImage *answer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return answer; }
```

Comment: I used overlay image scale is like         UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]];
   // [overlayImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 320, 400)];
    
    [overlayImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 50, 250, 250)];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayImageView];                                 But when i use [overlayImage drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0) 
          blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal 
              alpha: 1];     it gives small image size. Won't give what i set in CGRectMake.

Answer (score 1):

To merge two images in one image use the following code:

```
- (UIImage * ) mergeImage: (UIImage *) imageA withImage:  (UIImage *) imageB
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imageA.size.width, imageA.size.height), YES, 0.0);

[imageA drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0)];

[imageB drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(0,0)
          blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal // you can play with this
              alpha: 1]; // 0 - 1

UIImage *answer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return answer;

}
```