# How to save 2 UIImageView in one image to cameraroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have two UIImageView one over the other, and I'dlike to save them in one single file to camera roll.

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.myimage.image,nil,nil,nil);
});
```

the images are  laying on top of each other and are the same size. the top one has few alpha in order to see the other one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131050/ios-save-image-to-camera-roll

Comment: How are the image views related to each other? Are they the same size? There are numerous ways the images could be combined...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560082/how-to-merge-multiple-uiimageviews-into-one-uiimage

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way..,

Add your both imageview in one UIView., and then take screenshot of This UiView and stored generated image in your desired destination.

Here is Code to take screen shot by coding

```
// code to take Screen shot
-(void) takeScreenshot
{
    // Replace self.view with your view name which containing your ImageViews

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    // get a UIImage from the image context
    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // clean up drawing environment
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Then save your Image in your desired destination
}
```

Hope it will Help you, Happy Coding

Comment: it is not working for me can you show me a complete code example of the Action? including the save part i mean